# How to randomize ggplot factor color scheme, keeping same default distances on color wheel?

Tags: r, ggplot2

As I understand it, the ggplot2 package by default (i.e., option `scale_color_hue()`) uses orange and green for cases involving factors with two values, by picking values a certain distance apart on the color wheel. The default orange and green can be seen below.

```
library(ggplot2)

  xdf <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
  xdf$freq <- 1:nrow(xdf)
  ggplot(xdf, aes(x = X1, y = freq)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = factor(X8)), position = 'dodge')
```

[image: basic ggplot w/orange and green color scheme]
How can I create this graph using the same default color wheel distance between factors, but starting from a random (or chosen) color?

In particular, is there a way to do this using a random seed / taking one color value and automatically calculating this color wheel distance, besides just directly customizing `scale_fill_manual(colors)` ?

And if customizing `scale_fill_manual()` is the only way to accomplish this, how would I go about creating a function where I could input a random seed/start color and my number of factors for the color wheel spacing, that would return the list of colors spaced evenly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scale_fill_hue()` function can take a `h.start=` parameter to choose where you pick the first color (as described on the `?scale_fill_hue` help page)

```
ggplot(xdf, aes(x = X1, y = freq)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = factor(X8)), position = 'dodge')+
  scale_fill_hue(h.start = 120)
```

[image]